# Set default block classes in TinyMCE textarea when press return key or by default

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

I am very new to TinyMCE. I am working on my travel agency website. I need some `<textarea>` input for highlights, inclusions and exlusions.  For all these things I have created different `<textarea>` with tinymce.

I want one default block and style in one of my `<textarea>`. By default it should have a `<div>` with my custom classes from my stylesheet, where I can enter my content...

...like this when we load the page, in text area it should be div with this class.

```
<div class="small-12 columns highlight">My Content</div>
```

After pressing return, it should start with a new `<div>` with the same class, and so on on every return press.

```
<div class="small-12 columns highlight">Next Line</div>
```

This is my TinyMCE configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#tourplaces',
    theme : "advanced",
    forced_root_block: 'div',
    forced_root_block_attrs: { "class": "small-12 columns highlight"},
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"
    ],
    toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
    toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
    image_advtab: true,
    content_css: 'https://www.happyvoyaging.com/assets/voyage/global.css',
    content_css_cors: true,

    external_filemanager_path: "/public/filemanager/",
    filemanager_title: "Responsive Filemanager",
    external_plugins: {
        "filemanager": "/public/filemanager/plugin.min.js"
    }
});
```

If someone can help me with this, I would be thankful.

Comment: Any Support Please

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code should create a div with the specified classes already, since you modified the forced_root_block configs: https://codepen.io/pen/yLBXLrb